# How to authenticate user using Starscream

Tags: swift, websocket, starscream

I am stuck in user authentications; i want to authenticate user via username and password.

I did successfully connect via websocket but i don't know how to authenticate user i try lot of research over google but still i can't achieved my goal due to less number of work done on that.

The server API i want to request via JSON:

```
{ “UserName”: “UserName”, “Password”: “Password” }
```

and after request the server response is also JSON can some one please help me to achieve this. I am very thankful.

Basically i am new in **WebSocket in Swift 4** that's why i am facing lot of issues on that i just used cocoapods of Starcream.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any one please let me know ? not response till now. Kindly help me out.

Comment: WebSocket connection as usual may be accepted by server side only if you authenticate yourself in the request headers with smth like `Cookie: sesionid=11111`. It is odd to make authentication inside of open websocket connection. Can you provide more info about API to authentcate. Because here is nothong said where should it be posted

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample of Basic authentication with Starscream:

```
//Prepare autorization data
    let authString: String = "\(userName):\(password)"        
    let base64String = authString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!.base64EncodedString()

    // Prepare request and set headears for Basic Authorization
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: SERVER_URL)!)
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64String)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    //Initiate websocket
    socket = WebSocket(request: request)
    socket?.advancedDelegate = self
    socket?.connect()
```

If you got "invalid http upgrade" as result, just make sure you providing correct username and password.